# Counting triangles in triangular graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A *triangular graph* $T_n$ is the line graph of the complete graph $K_n$ (see for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularGraph.html)). Can you derive a formula for the number of triangles in the triangular graph $T_n$?

If not, can you at least find an asymptotic expression for it?

**Edit:** manual calculations lead me to believe that the answer is [A002417](http://oeis.org/A002417). Still can't see why.

Comment: Is this a homework question? you could at least write down some of your thoughts.

Comment: It's a strongly regular graph (the parameters are given in your link), so the eigenvalues and multiplicites of the adjacency matrix $A$ can be explicitly calculated. On the other hand, the number of triangles of the graph is one sixth of $tr(A^3)$. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: No, but I will give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work. I get $(n-2){n\choose 3}$ triangles. But now that I see the formula, there must be a simple proof!

Comment: Oh geez - you get a triangle in $T_n$ for every triangle in $K_n$ and for every $3$ edges meeting at a vertex, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The Fool's Method:* $T_n$ is an strongly regular graph with parameters $({n\choose 2}, 2(n-2),n-2,2)$, so its eigenvalues are $2(n-2)$ (with multiplicity $1$), $n-4$ (with multiplicity $n-1$) and $-2$ (with multiplicity $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$). So the number of triangles is one sixth of $$tr(A^3) = 8(n-2)^3+(n-4)^3(n-1)-4n(n-3).$$

*The KISS Method:* Triangles in $T_n$ arise either from a triangle in $K_n$ or from $3$ edges meeting at a vertex. Hence there are ${n\choose 3}+ n{n-1\choose 3}$ triangles.

Both formulas simplify to $(n-2){n\choose 3}$.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice ;)